# Как отключить минификацию css при автокомпиляции плагина less2css в sublime text 3

Tags: sublime-text-3, less

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отключить минификацию css при автокомпиляции плагина less2css в sublime text 3. Т.е. чтобы css автоматически не компилировался в одну строку. Нужно чтобы css был читабельно вида.

Answer (score 1):

В Sublime Text 3 заходим в Preference - Packages Settings - Less2Css - Settings User 
и вставляем("minify": false):
{
  "autoCompile": true,
  "createCssSourceMaps": false,
  "ignorePrefixedFiles": false,
  "lessBaseDir": "./",
  "lesscCommand": false,
  "main_file": false,
  "minify": false,
  "minName": false,
  "outputDir": "./",
  "outputFile": "", //[example.css] if left blank uses same name of .less file
  "showErrorWithWindow": true,
  "autoprefix": false,
  "disableVerbose":false,
  "silent":false
}